# loopback 4 integration with socket.io

Tags: loopbackjs, v4l2loopback

I'm working on a project which is built on loopback 4, and now the client is asking to have notifications and messaging.

I searched a lot to find the best way to integrate socket.io with loopback 4, no luck, I found nothing

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I use socket.io with loopback 3, the socket.io module connects to Server.js -> boot (). In loopback 4, so do not work?

Comment: I'm asking for an integration like that in sailsjs

Answer (score 2):

LoopBack 4 does not have a first-class support for websockets yet. Raymond Feng, LoopBack's architect, created an example project to demonstrate how to route socket.io messages to Controller classes, you can find the project here:

https://github.com/raymondfeng/loopback4-example-websocket/

Quoting from the README:

> This example is created to explore how to expose Websocket (socket.io)
>   endpoints in conjunction with LoopBack controllers.
>
> Similarly as @loopback/rest, each websocket server is attached to an
>   http/https server. WebSocket controllers are mapped to different
>   routes (namespaces), for example:
>
> - `/admins` -> `AdminController`
> - `/chats` -> `ChatController`
>
> When a client connects to the endpoint, a controller is instantiated
>   upon the connection event of the namespace with the socket object.
>   Controller methods can subscribe to one or more message types and send
>   messages to one or more clients.

Comment: Is there any example or tutorial to how integrate socket with rest in loopback 4? something like sailsjs

Comment: I opened an issue on that repo asking for step to step instructions on how to integrate that code with an lb4 app generated through the CLI